# Relationship and lookup in Access database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a big questionnaire form which i want to set up in Access database to set up data entry form for users. This has 200 different questions which i have categorised in 3 tables accordingly + 1 table(main info tbl) which has initial details i.e who is completing and other info to create 1 instance each time following those 200 same questions.

I have tried setting up primary key of MaininfoTbl as a foreign key (as ID 2) in rest of 3 tables in order to link the each instance of maininfoTbl entry followed by those 200 questions which are in 3 tables with no success, i have also tried using lookup so value of ID 2 in all 3 table should look up at primary key ID of maininfoTbl and mainint same ID to create 1 unique instance of data entry combining all 4 tables.

Also i have set up multi tab data entry form where first tab is of MaininfoTbl and rest 3 has questions from 3 tables. Having tried both look up and relationship building I have experience in the multitab form not all the ID fields are taking up ID no. from first tab which is maininfoTbl data entry form.

Can i please be guided to right direction on what wrong am i doing or is there way around to create such data entry form other than access (Excel is not an option as it goes all the way to 200 columns for each entry) I have tried searching all over internet without success (i am using 2010 access).
Any help in right direction is appreciated.

Comment: very surprised this question got down voted, i have mentioned what i tried so far and what result i got and what i am trying to achieve with some help. didnt ask for solution, asked for direction

Answer (score 1):

See http://fmsinc.com/tpapers/genaccess/databasenorm.html for an intro to table design. It goes through database normalization, which should help you with setting up your relationships correctly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, looks good Access help point but it doesn't provide much details unless buying tutorial products.